# Reviving iPad Air from the dead

Tags: ipad, hardware, repair

My iPad Air died a couple of days ago, I recorded its last dying breath >>
[Youtube](https://youtu.be/ICHFR2JhMSs)

Before it crashed for good my daughter was playing a disney game in Safari when she told me the screen turned blue than black. So I thought the battery was dead and plugged it in to not get it going again.

Later that day I tried al button combinations also plugged in (and out) of my macbook to get it going again. To no avail.

What would be the next best step?

- Disassemble / reassemble
- Send it of to Apple (is this expensive?)
- Option 3?

Model A1474 (FCC ID BCGA1474 IC 579C A1472)

## update

I've brought the device to a Apple certified service provider and they noticed the iPad was almost 2 years old and could be eligible for guaranty. They (Apple) replaced the device at zero cost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your video looks like it could be the Digitizer that's going bad.

Disassembling iPad, especially the Air series, is a huge pain in the ass (it's Repairability score on iFitIt is 2/10). If you want to go that route here's the info from iFixIt:

https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iPad_Air_Wi-Fi

Unlike the iPhones Apple doesn't replace the screens/digitizers because of the complicated repair process. They will however offer you a new iPad (same kind as what you have) with a Out Of Warranty exchange:

https://support.apple.com/ipad/repair/other

Comment: Great answer. $250 I find a bit steep for a two+ year old device. I think I will take a shot at repairing it. If that fails I give up. Although I would think the digitizer isn't the broken part, this only transfers gestures.

Comment: Take it from me Ralf, iPad Airs are incredibly hard to repair - I tried and failed. If you've never done it before, you may end up destroying it, and thus making it ineligible for the $250 repair from Apple. You might want to use the $250 and trade up to an iPad2.

Comment: @IconDaemon Ok I'll take you word for it. Will call Apple support and find out what the options are. It seems Out Of Warrenty Exchange is a US thing only? I don't get this option in the Netherlands it seems.

Comment: I've taken the iPad to a Apple Service center and they think that by Dutch law it will fall within guaranty because it broke down in 1.5 years.